# Having two images of docker for production and development

Tags: ubuntu, docker, production-environment

I  am starting to use docker but i am confused with difference between development environment and production.

Currently in my developement docker i use this

`docker run -d -v /home/code:/var/www/code` so that i can edit files form my host.

Now i want that in production i don't mount code as volume but rather ship it with all code.

So do i need to make separate images and use

`ADD /home/code:/var/www/code`

or is there any way to do that from one image only

Comment: Ideally, I think the difference between "Dev" and "Prod" should be scale (number of container instances) and access to data (Volumes or databases)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor can you please explain what u mean by that.; i want to know more about it

Comment: Package your software as a container, save it in a registry. Tagging the image in your registry enables you to run an version at any time on any machine. Useful for Dev and Test. Normally you'd run only a single instance in production. It should be launched the same way as in Dev, but you'd need more instances in order to handle larger loads. Secondly your production system would use it's own data, either in a data volume or a production database that developers would normally have no access to.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor thanks mark , i will tag conatiner like relaease 1,2,3 and i have database in separate container. The only thing which i was not sure was to have two separate images for dev and prod. like in prod `code` will be the part of image but in dev it will be mounted from host. is that correct way of doing or you recommend something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you have two images: `base` and `app` for example.

Your `base` image sets up everything except for your code. For example, if your app is written in Java it will setup the JDK. The `app` image is the one that you build and ship to production or other environments. This lets you use the `base` image during development by just mounting the volumes in as you did above.

Comment: No problem. Also, I just wanted to clarify, the `app` image should be `FROM base`.